# Do I need a JDBC driver if working on remote server

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am new to networking and database. I am doing a project for my database class incorporating java with SQL. I use putty to connect to the server at school and I can access my java files and everything just fine. But when I run my java file I get the "`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`". Now do I need to install a JDBC driver on my home PC ? I wouldn't think I do since I am running everything off the server at school just as if I were at school using putty to do the same thing.

I apologize for any vagueness, I honestly do not know too much about what I am doing. I have tried looking up solutions to my problem but I cannot understand what others are saying. Any information needed I will gladly provide, I just do not know what to provide.

Comment: What that exception is saying is that, on the environment you're running in, the Class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` was not provided on the classpath when running the java program. It's probably missing the `.jar` containing that class.

Comment: so it is not imported is what you are saying? Sorry I have very basic knowledge. All my work has been done in MySQL and JGRASP

Comment: You need a driver class in your application classpath. When you running application using putty, your actually runnig application on your school PC, please, provide exact command wich was used to run your application at home and at school

Comment: My instructor told us we would only have to do:
java TestMyQuery.java
at the command prompt (putty)

Comment: ^This command did not work. Got a "cannot find class 'TestMyQuery.java'" error. 

The command I used to get the driver error was:
java -classpath TestMyQuery.java

Comment: Is not the same to connect to the database server by putty than to do it with java. You need the connector jar. See my answer.

Comment: It's impossible in any case you should use construction like that java -cp /folderWithYourClasses:/pathToDriver.jar TestMyQuery

Answer (score 1):

When you run your java program on the remote server, you are currently missing the mysql jdbc driver from the classpath.

You need to run `javac` to compile your java class.

```
> javac TestMyQuery.java
```

This will produce a TestMyQuery.class file. To run the program, assuming it has a `main()` method:

```
> java -cp .;<the name of the jar containing the driver> TestMyQuery
```

Notice the `.;`, this adds the current directory to the classpath. This adds your TestMyQuery.class file to the class path as well.

Look in your remote server directories, maybe the jar is already somewhere in there.

Comment: Your forgot to add aplication classes in classpath

java -cp <the name of the jar containing the driver>:<classes folder> TestMyQuery

Comment: Any tips on how to find this jar?

Comment: @Gunnarr added current directory to classpath. Austin, It's usually called `mysql-connector-java-X.X.XX-bin.jar`.

Comment: @Austin: I did put the link in my comment. But you need to download the same version as the database.

Comment: @Sotirios when I used that it cannot find the java file again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [mysql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) jar to your class path. Download the connector jar for the exact version of MySQL of your database server.

Comment: So I need to ask my instructor what this is? Why isn't everything just taken from the server at school?

Comment: The reason is that in your school you already have the connector in the classpath. Probably added by your instructor.

Comment: how can I check the version of MySQL?

Comment: @Austin: Connect via putty and run the command "select version();". Will return something like "5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1". The version is, in this case, 5.5.29.

Answer (score 0):

You have generated a jar, if so, your MySQL JDBC driver must be included in the classpath. In your jar, you can copy the mysql driver in your "classes" folder of your jar or generate your jar again, but including the mysql as part of your project to get a jar with the driver inside.

Comment: Where would the "classes folder be? Near my java files or somewhere in the MySQL folders?

Answer (score 0):

My instructor gave me instructions on how to connect to the driver remotely. I did not have to do anything with a jar file or classpaths. Sorry for the time.